# How to deploy AWS using CDK, sagemaker?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-sagemaker

I want to use this [repo](https://github.com/amogh147/binance_takeHome_gemini_amogh) and I have created and activated a virtualenv and installed the required dependencies.

I get an error when I run pytest.

And under the file binance_cdk/app.py it describes the following tasks:

## App (PSVM method) entry point of the program.

## Note:

Steps tp setup CDK:

1. install npm
2. cdk -init (creates an empty project)
3. Add in your infrastructure code.
4. Run CDK synth
5. CDK bootstrap <aws_account>/
6. Run CDK deploy ---> This creates a cloudformation .yml file and the aws resources will be created as per the mentioned stack.

I'm stuck on step 3, what do I add in this infrastructure code, and if I want to use this on amazon sagemaker which I am not familiar with, do I even bother doing this on my local terminal, or do I do the whole process regardless on sagemaker?

Thank you in advance for your time and answers !